# Why are there holes in my cloudwatch logs?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have been running lambdas using C# with serverless.com framework for some months now, and I consistently notice holes in the cloudwatch logs.  So far it has only been an annoyance.  I have been looking around for some explanation, but it is starting to get to the point where I need to understand/fix the problem.

For instance, today I can see the lambda monitor shows hundreds to thousands of executions between 7AM and 8AM, but the cloudwatch logs show logfiles up until 7:19AM and then nothing again until 8:52AM.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to edit my question with screenshots and tallies of the data, I came upon the answer.  I thought it would be helpful for this to be a separate answer as it is extremely specific and enlightening.

The crux of the problem is that I didn't expect such huge gaps between invocation times and log write times.  12 minutes is an eternity compared to the work I have done in the past.

Consider this graph:

[image: Invocations]

12:59 UTC should be 7:59AM CST.  Counting the invocations between 12:59 and 13:08, I get roughly ~110.

Cloudwatch shows these log streams:
[image: log streams]

Looking at these log streams, there seems to be a large gap.  The timestamp on the log stream is the "file close" time.  The logstream for 8:08:37 includes events from 12 minutes before.

So the timestamps on the log streams are not very useful for finding debug data.  The search all has not been very helpful up until now either.  Slow and very limited.  I will look into some other method for crunching logs.

Comment: if searching your log files is your intent, you can make use of Log Insights (Inside CloudWatch) to write queries that parse a given log group (or multiple).

Answer (score 1):

Logs are by Invocation of the lambda and log group links are by concurrent executions. If you look at your lambda metrics, you will see a stat called ConcurrentExecution - this is the total number of simultaneous serverless lambda containers you have running at any given moment - but that does NOT equal the same as Invocations. The headless project im on is doing about 5k invocations an hour and we've never been above 5 concurrent executions of any of our 25ish lambda's (helps that they all run after start up at about 300ms)

So if you have 100 invocations in 10 seconds, but they all take less than a second to run, once a given lambda container is spun up it will be reused as long as it is continually receiving events. This is how AWS works around the 'cold start' problem as much as possible where a given lambda may take 10-15 or more seconds to start up. By trying to predict traffic flow (and you can manipulate these settings as well) AWS is attempting to have a warm lambda ready to go for you whenever you need it.

These concurrent executions are slowly shut down as their volume drops off, their calls brought back in to other ones that are still active.

What this means for Log Group logs is two fold:

1. you may see large 'gaps' in the times but if you look closely any given log group will have multiple invocations in it.
2. log groups are delayed by several seconds to several minutes depending on the server load, so at any given time you may not actually be seeing all the logs of a given moment.

The other possibility is that you logging is not set up correctly (Python lambda's in particular have difficulty in logging properly to cloudwatch - the default Logging Handler doesn't play nice with the way lambda boots up a handler to attach it to the logGroup)  or what you are getting is a ton of hits that are not actually doing anything - only pings/keep alive events that do not actually trigger any of your log statement - at which you will generally only see the concurrent start up/shutdown log statements (as stated above they are far fewer)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with gaps in log groups?
A log group gets its log by log streams and one of the same lambda container use the same log stream. So it may not be the most recent log stream in your log group that have the latest log entry.

Here you can read more about it:
https://dashbird.io/blog/how-to-save-hundreds-hours-debugging-lambda/